# Extend IBM Connections on an application level like blogs and forums

Tags: xpages, cors, connection

We are trying to extend IBM Connections 4.5 CR3 with own XPages apps not on the well described widget extension level for communities but on the application level.

Our goal is to extend the applications menu and load our apps inside the connections framework just like the original blogs or forums IBM apps.

Some others tried the same thing like this one:
http://blog.riand.com/2014/06/get-your-application-integrated-within.html?m=1

It seems that the trick for coming around the CORS trouble is not well documented in there.

Mikkel has put some code onto GitHub for the server side page generation:

https://github.com/lekkimworld/ic-wrapper

Can someone over here solve this or help us to come some steps further?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches you can take, depending how daring you are.

- The most pragmatic approach would be:
  Load a connections page, steal the HTML that makes up the Menu bar, copy that into a XPages custom control and you are done (of course you had added a link to your application beforehand in [LotusConnectionsConfig.xml](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_5.0.0/admin/admin/r_admin_common_config_files.dita?lang=en)
- Check the JSP that reads the LotusConnectionsConfig.xml how it is rendering the menu bar. Configure the Apache HTTP to expose the XML for read access, so you can dynamically create that menu - saves work when your menu changes often
- Use the approaches described by Phil
- Add a small JS that you call in your added menu. It would remove the content of the Connections page below the menu level and insert an iFrame which loads your XPage
- Cheat by building a widget for a community homepage and have just that one widget (taking the whole page as real estate) in that Community

That's just off my head. Hope it helps

Comment: Look at https://github.com/lekkimworld/ic-wrapper for details of the server side java code. Is this the solution? Can you evaluate it with success? Since there is not so much help in the read me we are not at all sure if we can turn this into action...